# How to show and use Quick actions/Context action in Neovim?

Tags: neovim, quickfix, lsp

JetBrains IDEs and VSCode have this feature where they show some actions that you can do to handle a warning like in the pictures below.

PyCharm's Context action:

[image: Pycharm's Context action]

VSCode's Quick fix

[image: VScode's Quick fix]

In Neovim, it does show a warning but I cannot find any way to show actions that I can do with that warning.

[image]

Currently, I'm using [kickstart.nvim](https://github.com/nvim-lua/kickstart.nvim) as my config.

Comment: I'm afraid without knowing how the warning is shown it will be difficult to answer. The _typical_ way stuff like this works these days is your editor connects to an LSP as a client, and receives diagnostic text like warnings. It can also request "actions" via the protocol. So, check your "distribution" (blech) documentation for how to trigger LSP actions. (RE: "blech," most experienced vimmers recommend against distributions and for building your own configuration. That way, you know what comes from where and how to manipulate it.)

Answer (score 0):

In Vim, "QuickFix" seems to refer to the old way of fixing code, which involves navigating a list of errors spat out by the compiler after you run `:make`. I think you want "Code Actions", which kickstart binds to `<leader>ca`.